# Angular 2 check for account before creating account

Tags: javascript, angular

I am subscribing to the following event list so

```
userService.createUser(this.form).subscribe((user)=>{ this.user = user })
```

The service method looks like this...

```
createAccount(user) {

        let headers = new Headers();
        headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        return this.http
            .post(
                '/api/accounts',
                JSON.stringify(user),
                {headers}
            )
            .map(res => res.json())
            .map((res) => {
                if (res['account']) {
                    this.authService.isLoggedIn = true;
                    this.loggedIn.next(true);
                    this.userData = res["account"];
                    return res;


                } else {

                    this.authService.isLoggedIn = false;

                }
            });

    }
```

I need to add a call like this somehow in the createUser to check if the user exists before it completes...

```
checkForDups(user){


        return this.http
            .get('/api/checkfordups/'+user.email)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .map((res) => {
                if (res>0) {
                    //user account exists...
                    return {'message' : 'User account exists!'};


                } else {

                    return true;

                }
            });
    }
```

I tried this...

```
createAccount(user) {

        if( this.checkForDups(user)){

            let headers = new Headers();
            headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

            return this.http
                .post(
                    '/api/accounts',
                    JSON.stringify(user),
                    {headers}
                )
                .map(res => res.json())
                .map((res) => {
                    if (res['account']) {
                        this.authService.isLoggedIn = true;
                        this.loggedIn.next(true);
                        this.userData = res["account"];
                        return res;


                    } else {

                        this.authService.isLoggedIn = false;

                    }
                });
        }else{


            return {"message": "duplicate account found"};
        }

    }
```

But it is not working correctly. Any idea on a better approach?

Answer (score 0):

In your last code you can subscribe to the checkForDups instead of calling it inside an if statement. Something like this:

```
    createAccount(user) {

        this.checkForDups(user)
        then.(result => {

            if( this.checkForDups(user)){

                let headers = new Headers();
                headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

                return this.http
                    .post(
                        '/api/accounts',
                        JSON.stringify(user),
                        {headers}
                    )
                    .map(res => res.json())
                    .map((res) => {
                        if (res['account']) {
                            this.authService.isLoggedIn = true;
                            this.loggedIn.next(true);
                            this.userData = res["account"];
                            return res;


                        } else {

                            this.authService.isLoggedIn = false;

                        }
                    });
            }else{


                return {"message": "duplicate account found"};
            }

        });

    }
```

And int your checkForDups, do not forget to call `.toPromise()` after http call as:

```
    import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise'; // import the .toPromisse method here
    ...
    checkForDups(user){


        return this.http
            .get('/api/checkfordups/'+user.email)
            .map(res => res.json())
            .map((res) => {
                if (res>0) {
                    //user account exists...
                    return {'message' : 'User account exists!'};


                } else {

                    return true;

                }
            })
            .toPromise(); // do not forget this so you would not be able to call the `.then(...)` method inside createAccount
    }
```

Comment: capp/components/user-service/user.service.ts(82,16): error TS2339: Property 'toPromise' does not exist on type 'Observable<void>'.
app/components/user-service/user.service.ts(87,19): error TS2354: No best common type exists among return expressions.
app/components/user/user.component.ts(41,42): error TS2339: Property 'subscribe' does not exist on type 'void'.

Comment: Just import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';